# Git: local tags are not exported to github?

Tags: git, github

We are two people (Alice and Bob) working on a project. We use git and github to collaborate.
I try to synthesize my question hereafter:

```
[alice@pcA projectX]$ git tag
0.1
0.2
0.3

[alice@pc1 project1]$ git add . -A && git commit -m "my commit description" && git push origin master

...

[bob@pcB projectX]$ git pull

[bob@pcB projectX]$ git tag
   <== EMPTY LIST...
```

I mean, I would expect Bob to share Alice's tags... What does Bob miss?

*I did just notice tags are **not** available on github web interface, either...*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the option `--tags`:

```
git push --tags origin master
```

Comment: It will push both tags and commits

Comment: If you want more control, you can of course specify the tags individually: `git push origin tag1 tag2 branch1 branch2`. They are refs like branches too after all.